# Как присвоить переменной String значение из файла Strings?

Tags: java, android

Проблема в том, что когда я присваиваю строке значение из файла `strings` в классе активности через `String string = getResources().getString(R.string.test);` все присваивается нормально, но в отдельном классе адаптера при попытке такой записи студия даже не предлагает в подсказках такой код, как же получить ссылку на ресурс в таком случае?

Comment: В конструктор адаптера передавайте `Context` и используйте его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При создании адаптера передаете в него контекст. Потом используете его для получения доступа к ресурсам.

```
String string = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.test);
```

Comment: работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Если строка нужна в методе `onBindViewHolder`, то контекст для её получения можно взять из корневой вьюхи `ViewHolder`-а так:

```
holder.itemView.getContext().getString(R.string.app_name);
```